# How to get Google charts animation example working on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

Right I'm doing this for a friend so please don't annihilate me.

I want to get one of the more complex examples working from 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation

On a webpage, and also, ideally, on js fiddle.

I've tried surrounding it in html and body tags, tried creating a div tag to place the graph, tried including various libraries, none of it would work either as a webpage, or on JS fiddle.

What I need is to have it working in js fiddle, and then instruction on the tags I need to add to javascript in js fiddle to get it working as a stand alone webpage.  JS Fiddle clearly going to help me get it adapted quicker.

Help!

```
   // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
var rowData1 = [['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua  Guinea',
                 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
                ['2004/05', 165, 938, 522, 998, 450, 114.6],
                ['2005/06', 135, 1120, 599, 1268, 288, 382],
                ['2006/07', 157, 1167, 587, 807, 397, 623],
                ['2007/08', 139, 1110, 615, 968, 215, 409.4],
                ['2008/09', 136, 691, 629, 1026, 366, 569.6]];
var rowData2 = [['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua  Guinea',
                 'Rwanda', 'Average'],
                ['2004/05', 122, 638, 722, 998, 450, 614.6],
                ['2005/06', 100, 1120, 899, 1268, 288, 682],
                ['2006/07', 183, 167, 487, 207, 397, 623],
                ['2007/08', 200, 510, 315, 1068, 215, 609.4],
                ['2008/09', 123, 491, 829, 826, 366, 569.6]];

// Create and populate the data tables.
var data = [];
data[0] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData1);
data[1] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData2);

var options = {
  width: 400,
  height: 240,
  vAxis: {title: "Cups"},
  hAxis: {title: "Month"},
  seriesType: "bars",
  series: {5: {type: "line"}},
  animation:{
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'out'
  },
};
var current = 0;
// Create and draw the visualization.
var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
var button = document.getElementById('b1');
function drawChart() {
  // Disabling the button while the chart is drawing.
  button.disabled = true;
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready',
      function() {
        button.disabled = false;
        button.value = 'Switch to ' + (current ? 'Tea' : 'Coffee');
      });
  options['title'] = 'Monthly ' + (current ? 'Coffee' : 'Tea') + ' Production by Country';

  chart.draw(data[current], options);
}
drawChart();

button.onclick = function() {
  current = 1 - current;
  drawChart();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have not referenced correctly,

```
   google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
        function init(){
              var rowData1 = [['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua  Guinea',
                         'Rwanda', 'Average'],
                        ['2004/05', 165, 938, 522, 998, 450, 114.6],
                        ['2005/06', 135, 1120, 599, 1268, 288, 382],
                        ['2006/07', 157, 1167, 587, 807, 397, 623],
                        ['2007/08', 139, 1110, 615, 968, 215, 409.4],
                        ['2008/09', 136, 691, 629, 1026, 366, 569.6]];
            var rowData2 = [['Month', 'Bolivia', 'Ecuador', 'Madagascar', 'Papua  Guinea',
                             'Rwanda', 'Average'],
                            ['2004/05', 122, 638, 722, 998, 450, 614.6],
                            ['2005/06', 100, 1120, 899, 1268, 288, 682],
                            ['2006/07', 183, 167, 487, 207, 397, 623],
                            ['2007/08', 200, 510, 315, 1068, 215, 609.4],
                            ['2008/09', 123, 491, 829, 826, 366, 569.6]];

            // Create and populate the data tables.
            var data = [];
            data[0] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData1);
            data[1] = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rowData2);

            var options = {
              width: 400,
              height: 240,
              vAxis: {title: "Cups"},
              hAxis: {title: "Month"},
              seriesType: "bars",
              series: {5: {type: "line"}},
              animation:{
                duration: 1000,
                easing: 'out'
              },
            };
            var current = 0;
            // Create and draw the visualization.
            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            var button = document.getElementById('b1');
            function drawChart() {
              // Disabling the button while the chart is drawing.
              button.disabled = true;
              google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready',
                  function() {
                    button.disabled = false;
                    button.value = 'Switch to ' + (current ? 'Tea' : 'Coffee');
                  });
              options['title'] = 'Monthly ' + (current ? 'Coffee' : 'Tea') + ' Production by Country';

              chart.draw(data[current], options);
            }
            drawChart();

            button.onclick = function() {
              current = 1 - current;
              drawChart();
            }
        }
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/u3w5bdfu/11/)**

Comment: Ahhhhh!  you beauty! :)  Let me give you a big KISS, X.